# Error [WinError 10054] when sending email TO gmail.com via smtplib from my VPS (other domains are ok)

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I'm struggling for few days on this problem : i can't send a mail to a gmail address (other domains such outlook or my own etc. are ok). My domain is hosted on a VPS and no email filter (anti spam) are set.

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("MYADRRESSSERVER",465)
server.login("MYLOGIN","SMYPASSWORD")
server.sendmail("MYEMAILADDRESS",
                "recipient@gmail.com",
                "Lets go baby!")
server.quit()
```

> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant

"Une connexion existante ..." means "Distant connection has been closed by distant host"

Any idea on the origin or solution for this? Thanks in advance for your help.
Best regards

Comment: Are you connecting to gmail or your own server? Can you check the server logs or turn on logging in your code? If it was a problem with gmail, your server should accept the mail and try to relay it, eventually bouncing it if it cannot be delivered. But this would happen much later than in your connection.

Comment: Hi robert. From my own server (vps hosted by lws)

Comment: I discovered something stranger. When i'm connected to this vps (ISP config open) - the mail is sent to gmail without error (no problem with @ msn.com or @ mydomain.com...